# Android Pass class data into ListVew with getSupportFragmentManager

Tags: android, android-sqlite

after get Data from `webServer` or `DataBase` i want to pass data to `ListView` with `getSupportFragmentManager`. this method get an data from class with this structure:

```
public class ReceiveFields {

    public long lastId;
    public String 
    public String 
    public String 
    public String 
    public String 
    private Context 
    public 
  }
}
```

Pass and get data from database:

```
ListSMS = db.getAllReceivedSMSFromDatabase();
```

`getAllReceivedSMSFromDatabase` function:

```
public List<ReceiveFields> getAllReceivedSMSFromDatabase() {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + this.RECEIVE_FIELDS_TABLE ;

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        List<ReceiveFields> ListSMS = new ArrayList<ReceiveFields>();

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            ListSMS.add(new ReceiveFields(

                    Long.valueOf(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lastId"))),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("smsNumber")),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("mobileNumber")),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("senderName")),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("smsBody")),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("receiveDate"))));

        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        return ListSMS;

    }
```

`getAllReceivedSMSFromDatabase` function not have any problem and can be return data as `List<ReceiveFields>`

create and pass data into `ListView`:

```
List<ReceiveFields> receivedSMSList = db.getAllReceivedSMSFromDatabase();

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.drawer, ListSMS).commit();
```

i get an arror now :

```
Error:(288, 63) java: no suitable method found for replace(int,java.util.List<ir.tsms.wsdl.ReceiveFields>)
    method android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction.replace(int,android.support.v4.app.Fragment,java.lang.String) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction.replace(int,android.support.v4.app.Fragment) is not applicable
      (actual argument java.util.List<ir.tsms.wsdl.ReceiveFields> cannot be converted to android.support.v4.app.Fragment by method invocation conversion)
```

Screen Shot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As i get it right You are trying to replace a `List` instead of a `Fragment` , getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace expect a placeholder and a Fragment Object which you didn't provide .

Edit : 
you cannot pass your data structure to your Fragment this way by replace! you can get yourFragment object after you replaced it then pass your data as an argument to it or define an interface and implement callBack methods  :

```
YouFragment frag = (YouFragment) SupportfragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("YourFragment");
frag.initList(ReceivedSmsList);
```

Comment: thats not have an problem and i can pass data handly and that can show correctly. i think my returned value as `List<ReceiveFields>` is not coccrect. POST UPDATED

Comment: @TuxWorld : its exactly what i said , You have to use replace with a Placeholder and a Fragment not a Placeholder and a List.